# Pure Java MyBatis Mappers?

Tags: java, spring, orm, ibatis, mybatis

I have a project that uses Mybatis (v3.0.5) for OR/mapping. The typical (functioning) set up is as follows:

1. A POJO to map - `Fruit`
2. A "MyBatis" mapper XML file - `FruitMapper.xml` - where all the SQL queries go
3. An interface mapper that defines all the same mapper methods - `FruitMapper.java`
4. A DAO that has an interface mapper reference - `FruitDao`
5. A MyBatis config file - `mybatis-config.xml`
6. Linking everything together with Spring config XML - `myapp-spring-config.xml`

A sample implementation:

```
public class Fruit {
    private String type = "Orange"; // Orange by default!

    // Getters & setters, etc. This is just a VO/POJO
    // that corresponds to a [fruits] table in my DB.
}

public interface FruitMapper {
    public List<Fruit> getAllFruits();
}


public class FruitDao {
    private FruitMapper mapper;

    // Getters & setters

    public List<Fruit> getAllFruits() {
        return mapper.getAllFruits();
    }
}
```

FruitMapper.xml

```
<mapper namespace="net.me.myapp.FruitMapper">
    <select id="getAllFruits" resultSetType="FORWARD_ONLY">
        SELECT * FROM fruits
    </select>
</mapper>
```

mybatis-config.xml

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Nothing special here. -->
</configuration>
```

myapp-spring-config.xml: (THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO GET RID OF)

```
<bean id="fruitDao" class="net.me.myapp.FruitDao">
    <property name="mapper" ref="fruitMapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="fruitMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">  
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="net.me.myapp.FruitMapper" />
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDatasource" /> 
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml" />
    <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath:*Mapper.xml" />
</bean>
<bean id="myDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/comp/env/jdbc/our-mysql-database</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This works great. However, I'm not a huge fan of spring and was wondering how I would implement my own, pure Java, version of what all the beans in the Spring config file do.

So I ask: **what "glue code"/classes do I need to write to properly implement `FruitMapper.java` such that it will be bound to `FruitMapper.xml` at runtime?** Such that whenever I write:

```
FruitMapperDao dao = new FruitMapperDao();
FruitMapperImpl mapper = new FruitMapperImpl(); // <== this is what I need to implement here
dao.setMapper(mapper);

List<Fruit> allFruits = dao.getAllFruits();
```

...then I should get a list of all `fruit` records in my data source? Thanks in advance!

#### UPDATE

I should also mention that, given the setup above, I need both `mybatis.jar` and `mybatis-spring.jar` on the runtime classpath. I want to get rid of Spring altogether, and not require any Spring jars or classes for my pure Java solution to work!

Comment: You can use Java classes that contain SQL Mapping Annotations to avoid the need for XML. 
public interface BlogMapper {
  @Select("SELECT * FROM blog WHERE id = #{id}")
  Blog selectBlog(int id);
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to obtain an `SqlSession` instance (e.g. named `session`) and invoke method `session.getMapper(FruitMapper.class)`. You will obtain an object that already implements mapper interface, then just call it's methods to obtain data from DB.

P.S. You can obtain SqlSession without Spring like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream("/mybatis-config.xml");
SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(inputStream);
SqlSession session = factory.openSession();
```